# How to escape 1 or more whitespaces in a regex in the lineinfile module of Ansible?

Tags: regex, yaml, ansible

I am using Ansible to set some variables on a file using the `lineinfile` module.
The problem I'm bumping into is how to have a regular expression that is flexible enough to have some spaces in the middle of the string. Please see below:

```
- name: Set DB IP in db conn file
  lineinfile: 
    dest=/path/to/db_conn
    regexp="{{ item.regexp }}"
    line="{{ item.line }}"
  with_items:
    - { regexp: "^.?dbschema_audit=",
        line: "$dbschema_audit=\'{{ db_schema_audit }}\';" }
    - { regexp: "^.?dbschema_audit_trail\s\*=",
        line: "$dbschema_audit_trail=\'{{ db_schema_audit_trail }}\';" }
```

The file I'm trying to change has lines like these:

```
$dbschema_audit='a';
$dbschema_audit_trail ='a';
```

I have tried different variations of `\s*` with `{`, `'` and `\` and nothing seems to work. Can I have some wisdom from out there?

Comment: \s\\* will match one space and one * literaly.  \s* will match 0 to N space caracter.

Comment: That's what I would think as well. Problem is, Ansible/YAML does not like the notation: "The offending line appears to be:

    - { regexp: "^\\$dbschema_audit\s*=", line: "$dbschema_audit=\'{{ db_schema_audit }}\';" }   "

Comment: Try `regexp: "^.?dbschema_audit\s{0,}="` or `regexp: "^.?dbschema_audit[ \t\r\n\f\v]{0,}="`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ansible playbooks are in YAML format. In a double quoted scalar, character sequences starting with the `\` character are escape sequences, but the [YAML specification](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2517668) says `\s` is a not a valid escape sequence.

In a double quoted scalar, you would have to write

```
"\\s"
```

Alternatively, in a single quoted scalar, the `\` character has no special meaning, so you can write

```
'\s'
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! `regexp: "^\\$dbschema_audit_trail\\s*="` worked