# Ansible: How to add a line which contains "tabs" or create a variable which contains tabs like XLS?

Tags: ansible

In Ansible, how to add a line which contains "tabs" or create a variable which contains tabs like XLS?

In shell script I am able to write below line as a tab separator

```bash
print $date "\t" $host_name >> logfile.xls
```

Now I am trying to write the header to a file using variable with tabs (in XLS tabs default to 8 spaces) something like this

```yaml
header_value=: 'Date        Host Name'
```

When I am writing this variable to my file as header, instead of taking as two cells/columns it is writing in one column.

Is there a way to have a tab separator in ansible variable? or can I use the shell or command to write the header to a file?

```yaml
- name: Write header log file
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: false
  run_once: yes
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: "{{ logfile }}.xls"
    insertbefore: BOF
    line: "{{ header_value }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the tabulator `\t` in your variables as in your `print` example.

For a test file

```bash
cat tab.file
today   localhost
```

the example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    HEADER: "Date\tHost_Name"

  tasks:

  - name: Write header to file
    lineinfile:
      path: tab.file
      insertbefore: BOF
      line: "{{ HEADER }}"
```

will result into the changed file

```bash
cat tab.file
Date    Host_Name
today   localhost
```

**Documentation**

- [YAML Syntax - Gotchas](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas)

  > *The difference between single quotes and double quotes is that in double quotes you can use escapes ... The list of allowed escapes can be found in the YAML Specification under [“Escape Sequences” (YAML 1.1)](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id872840) or [“Escape Characters” (YAML 1.2)](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#57-escaped-characters).*

**Further Reading**

- [`lineinfile` module incorrectly converts tab characters to `\t` in files](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/1892#issuecomment-132754634)

  > *... this is because YAML requires escape strings to be enclosed by double-quotes. The playbook below (using double-quotes) operates as expected.*
- [How to escape ... in the `lineinfile` module of Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38491899/6771046)

  > *In a double quoted scalar, character sequences starting with the `\` character are escape sequences*